# How to count all people in all voice channel of server

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots

I am using typescript and I used this code: but it doesn't work

```js
let count = 0;
const userCount = client.guilds.cache.get("MY Server_ID")?.channels.cache.filter(ch => ch.type === "GUILD_VOICE").map((ch) => count  +=  ch.members.size);
```

ERROR:

```
Property 'size' does not exist on type 'Collection<string, GuildMember> | ThreadMemberManager'.
  Property 'size' does not exist on type 'ThreadMemberManager'.
```

docs said that  ch.members have `said` but it gives an error

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=members
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'll need to add a typecheck of whether or not the returning value `ch.members` is a GuildMember Collection.

Comment: can you make an example? @Elitezen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.isVoice()` type guard and `Array#reduce()`

```js
let channels = client.guilds.cache.get("MY Server_ID")?.channels.cache.filter(ch => ch.type === "GUILD_VOICE")
let userCount = channels.reduce((a, c) => {
  if (!c.isVoice()) return;
  return a + c.members.size
}, 0) // should be member count in all channels
```

But, a better way to check the amount of people who are in a VC is by filtering members

```js
await client.guilds.cache.get("MY Server_ID")?.members.fetch()
let userCount = client.guilds.cache.get("MY Server_ID")?.members.cache.filter(m => m.voice.channel).size
```

Comment: thanks but I think `cache` has problem because in some case didn't work correctly @MrMythical

Comment: Try using Guild.members.fetch()